# I want to return html in a flask route

Tags: python, flask

Instead of using send_static_file, I want to use something like `html('<h1>content</h1>')`, sort of like jsonify.

```
@app.route('/incorrect_pass')
def incorrect_pass():
    return html('Incorrect password. <a href="/">Go back?</a>')
```

Is what I want to do.

Comment: just do `return 'Incorrect password. <a href="/">Go back?</a>'`. HTML is the default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind. Should've checked. Flask returns strings as html, so the `html()` isn't necessary above.

Comment: Yeah - Only difference with my answer is you can modify the head (so stylesheet etc)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
def html(content):  # Also allows you to set your own <head></head> etc
   return '<html><head>custom head stuff here</head><body>' + content + '</body></html>'

@app.route('/incorrect_pass')
def incorrect_pass():
    return html('Incorrect password. <a href="/">Go back?</a>')
    # OR return  'Incorrect password. <a href="/">Go back?</a>
```