# Flask send html element as jsonify

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jsonify

I am trying to send a HTML element in a message of jsonify object.

```
message = "Hello I am here click: <a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">{0}/a>".format(link)
response_data = {"status": "OK", "result": message}
return jsonify(response_data)
```

But when I am running on webpage it's coming as.

```
Hello I am here click: <a href="www.link.com" target=\"_blank\">www.link.com/a>"
```

How can I get rid of HTML `a` element and it's parameter?

Expected Output:

```
Hello I am here click: www.link.com
```

Comment: You can change the `message` variable and remove the `a` element and its parameter. I am sure that this is not what you are asking, but it is the answer. Could you clarify what you want to achieve / your expected output?

Comment: @MariusSiuram I want that link to be clickable on the browser so that's why need to add an href there.

Comment: If you simply return a string it will be considered as html see this answer for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298146/i-want-to-return-html-in-a-flask-route

Comment: where are you calling this method?

Comment: A JSON will never be clickable _per se_, JSON understand basic types but has no further semantics. Maybe you are confusing duties that need to do done at the *frontend*. Is your question "how do I render an <a> tag coming from a JSON response?". That should be addressed at Javascript level (frontend). You can drop python, flask and jsonify tags as they are irrelevant --and add your frontend code.